# Can we use one datasource for multiple databases?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have multiple PostgreSQL Database. I want to access them using one data source in spring boot. Is there anyway i can do this? I do not want to create datasource per database. I only want to create one. How can i do that?

I tried to create custom data source but could not do it

Comment: Sari, do you have multiple databases or a single database having multiple schemas? If it's the latter, then it's possible to use a single DataSource in Spring boot.

Comment: @dsp_user multiple databases

Comment: How do you want to control which database you are accessing?